# Combining two scripts

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm using two different scripts which work fine separately but would like to merge the two into one script.

Any help is welcomed. (please see scripts below)

SCRIPT 1 strips the file name to the last 3 characters:

```
on open whichFile
    repeat with aFile in whichFile
        tell application "Finder"
            set filename to name of aFile
            set name of aFile to ((characters -1 thru -7 of filename) as string)
            --set name of whichFile to ((characters 1 thru -4 of filename) as string) --trim last 3


        end tell
    end repeat
```

SCRIPT 2 adds the folder name (where the files reside) to the filename:

```
on open theDroppedItems
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to theCurrentDroppedItem as string

        tell application "System Events"
            set folderPath to theCurrentDroppedItem as string
            --display dialog (folderPath)
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
            set newFileName to (text item -4 of folderPath as string) & "-" & (text item -2 of folderPath as string) & "-" & (text item -1 of folderPath as string)
            --display dialog (newFileName)

            --rename file
            set fileAlias to (theCurrentDroppedItem) as alias
            set the name of fileAlias to newFileName

        end tell

    end repeat
end open
```

I would like to merge these two into one single script so I only need to run one, but am unsure how to do this?

Comment: What does each applesript do? What should the combined script do? Where did you get these scripts?  Links please.

Comment: @bmike .  The first script strips the file name to the last 3 characters, the second one adds the folder name(to the filename) where the files reside.

Comment: You’d need to rewrite one script.

Comment: The file name includes the extension - are you assuming an extension length when trimming the name?